# C# OAuth with service based application

Tags: c#, oauth

I have a service based application which need to connect to an API with OAuth authentification. I had a look to DotNetOpenAuth but things are not clear for me.
DotNetOpenAuth seems to works with web based application only, right ?

What is the best way to implement OAuth ?

Thanks for your help / advises

Answer (score 0):

In that case you need to use Token base authentication for Web-Api and your service based application based application.
DotNetOpenAuth is used to basically MVC application.

Some useful links 
1. https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Token-Based-Authentication-6db2acc9 
2. https://blogs.perficient.com/2017/06/11/token-based-authentication-in-web-api-2-via-owin/